# Date comparison with EPOCH to find an expiry in bash script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for ADDR in `netstat -plant|grep LISTEN|grep http|awk '{print $4}'|egrep -v ':80$|:5555$'|sort -u`; do
  EXPDATE=`openssl s_time 2>/dev/null | openssl s_client -connect $ADDR 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -dates 2>/dev/null | grep ^notA | cut -f2 -d= | sed -e "s/ GMT//"`
  printf "\t\t\t|%s\t|%s\t|\t%s\t|\n" "$ADDR" "$EXPDATE"
done

EXPDATES="$(echo "$EXPDATE" | awk '{print $1,$2,$4,$3}')"
CURREPOCH="$(date +%s)"

for i in "$EXPDATES"; do
  CREXPEPOCH="$(date +%s -d "$i")"
  if [[ "$CURREPOCH" -gt "$CREXPEPOCH" ]]; then
    echo "No Expiry Found."
  else
    echo "Cert expired"
  fi
done
```

Here, I'm getting dates from EXPDATE which has multiple date values as shown below,

```
Jul 12 12:00:00 2019
Jun 18 12:00:00 2019
May  8 00:00:00 2018
Nov 14 00:00:00 2017
```

And, converting to EPOCH time for better comparison with current EPOCH..

If any past date found, script should return "expired", else "no expiry found"..

I tried above script which is not working..

How I can do that? Any help?

Comment: Huh? `EXPDATES` is a string, not an array. `for i in "$EXPDATES"` will only iterate *exactly once*.

Comment: See [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: And btw, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; user-defined names should have at least one lowercase character. See relevant POSIX specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace (setting the latter will overwrite the former if like-named).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below tracks contents in an array rather than trying to abuse strings as iterable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# return all addresses that smell like HTTP
get_addrs() {
  netstat -plant \
  | awk '/LISTEN/ && /http/ && ! ($4 ~ /:(80|5555)$/) { print $4; }' \
  | sort -u
}

# Given a local server address, return a usable client address
# converts wildcard addresses to loopback ones.
clientAddr() {
  local addr=$1
  case $addr in
    0.0.0.0:*) addr=127.0.0.1:${addr#0.0.0.0:} ;;
    :::*)      addr='localhost:'"${addr#:::}"  ;;
  esac
  printf '%s\n' "$addr"
}

# Given a local address that runs a HTTPS server, return the last valid date for its certificate
endDateForAddr() {
  local addr endDate
  addr=$(clientAddr "$1") || return
  endDate=$(openssl s_client -connect "${addr}" </dev/null 2>/dev/null \
            | openssl x509 -dates \
            | awk -F= '/^notAfter/ { print $2; exit }')
  [[ $endDate ]] && printf '%s\n' "$endDate"
}

# Loop over our local HTTPS services...
expDates=( )
while read -r addr; do
  # find an address we can use to refer to each...
  addr=$(clientAddr "$addr") || continue
  # ...and use that to find its certificate expirey date.
  result=$(endDateForAddr "$addr") || continue
  # then add that to our array.
  expDates+=( "$result" )
done < <(get_addrs)

# in bash 4.3, this is more efficiently written: printf -v curr_epoch '%(%s)T' -1
curr_epoch="$(date +%s)"

for expdate in "${expDates[@]}"; do
  exp_epoch=$(date +%s -d "$expdate")
  if (( curr_epoch > exp_epoch )); then
    echo "$expdate is in the past"
  else
    echo "$expdate is in the future"
  fi
done
```

...its output (correct as of this writing):

```
Jul 12 12:00:00 2019 is in the future
Jun 18 12:00:00 2019 is in the future
May  8 00:00:00 2018 is in the future
Nov 14 00:00:00 2017 is in the future
```

Comment: Hi Charles, can we get the dates from $EXPDATE rather than declaring, because I really don't know what the dates it would be in each device.. 

$EXPDATE is in another for loop which provides the DATES in the above format..

How we can accommodate this script in existing for loop?

Comment: @Manoj.V, what's the format of `EXPDATE`? If you run `declare -p EXPDATE` at the front of your script, *exactly* what does it return?

Comment: @Manoj.V, ...if it's a string with newlines, then you could use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a expdates <<<"$EXPDATE"` to read the string into an array.

Comment: @Manoj.V, however, it would be much better if you modified the rest of your script to make the data be an array in the first place -- for instance, setting `expdates=( )` at the top to initialize it as an empty array, and inside your later `for` loop, run `expdates+=( "$new_date" )` to append a new array element.

Comment: for AAA in BBB
do
EXPDATE=XXXX
printf "$EXPDATE"
done

Through this above, I'm getting the output as below...

Jul 12 12:00:00 2019
Jun 18 12:00:00 2019
May  8 00:00:00 2018
Nov 14 00:00:00 2017

From this o/p, how I can compare with the current EPOCH?

Comment: `printf "$EXPDATE"` is awful -- that's passing your *data* in the position reserved for the *format string*. In many other languages' implementations of `printf` (including C's), that practice actually directly causes security bugs. You should either `printf '%s' "$EXPDATE"` or `printf '%b' "$EXPDATE"`, depending on whether you want the values to be literal or to have format-strings honored (changing `\n` to a newline, for example). Or `printf '%b\n' "$EXPDATE"`, if you want to honor format strings and append a trailing newline; etc, change to fit.

Comment: That said, I really need newlines &c. to be able to grok the nuances, so a comment field isn't a good format. Could you perhaps post a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Can you edit yours and show the modification? In comment section, formats are not doing well....

Comment: No, I can't really edit it, because I don't know what kind of source you're populating your original `EXPDATE` from. Could you edit the question to make that clear? (Is it a file? A command that emits one line per expiration date? Something else?)

Comment: I've edited. I believe, its clear now.. $EXPDATE returns the expiry date one by one.. And, with expiry date, I making the comparison with current date..

Comment: Yea gawds, that's awful. StackOverflow's scope doesn't *usually* extend to "do my work for me" questions, but in this case, I think a full rewrite was appropriate. You'll see the code is now structured into individual functions, each of which can be tested and invoked individually; and that the results are *always* stored in an array, not stuffed into a string and later split back out again.

Comment: Thank you Charles.. You've done your extended support... Appreciated... Let me have this tested and come back... Thanks again...

Comment: can you please let me know,  why we need "clientAddr( )" function to use loopback?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't a loopback address, it's a wildcard address. So if you say you're listening for connections *coming from* `0.0.0.0`, that means you're listening for connections without caring that they're coming from anywhere in particular. But just because you can have a socket listening for inbound connections that don't *come from* anywhere in particular doesn't mean you can turn it around the other way and have an outbound connection that isn't *going to* anywhere in particular.

Comment: Thank you Charles!!! This modified script works awesome.. In my script, it was carrying empty lines means some addresses doesn't have valid certificate whereas your script shows only valid entries without empty lines.